# Does react suggest, how many nested component should be used in an application?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Is creating more than 3 levels of nested components in react a bad practice? If yes, what are other ways to create complex UI without diluting a component's responsibility?

Answer (score 2):

No but if they have lots of props passing down to each other then it is.

solution is:

REDUX! Or React Context Api

creates a global state container. so components can be decoupled from each other

https://redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

The levels of nested components doesn't matter anymore than the level of nested HTML elements matters.

If on the other hand you're passing props more than 3-4 levels deep, that is not recommended. React's Context API was created to solve that. It helps you setup Provider/Consumer pairs that can inject props at any level. Here's a good example from React docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context